# What is the best rate at which to send updates to clients for a first person shooter NodeJS WebSocket server?

Tags: webgl, three.js, websocket

I developed a multiplayer FPS using WebGL, Nodejs and WebSockets.
So far it is running great.

I am currently using setInterval(sendPlayerPositions, 16); to send updates to WebGL clients.
Ideally I would use 16.66667 but this is not possible to my understanding.

So I wonder if I should change to setInterval(sendPlayerPositions, 10); to make up for the drift.
And in general it might be a good idea to send stuff faster than the client frame rate (60 in most cases).

I also recently learned about process.nextTick and setImmediate and I wonder if I should use those
instead...

Any advice ?

PS: I am currently using Nodejs 10 on my Linux server and Nodejs 14 on my dev machine.

Comment: There's usually no single "best" answer for this type of question. It depends on the needs of the game, the capabilities of your server, the way your packets are structured, the specific lag-compensation techniques you use, etc. There shouldn't be any need to send packets more frequently than the screen refresh rate; at that point you're just creating extra network overhead that the player doesn't benefit from.

Comment: This article is very good: http://buildnewgames.com/real-time-multiplayer/ I uploaded an example from this article, try to run it: https://battle-world.herokuapp.com/?debug Source code of this example: https://github.com/ruby0x1/realtime-multiplayer-in-html5

Answer (score 0):

Sending updates constantly with each server frame limits the amount of data you can send and might cause unnecessary work on both - server and the client.

A good idea is to send only changes in the world and implement physics/behaviour for both - server and client.

> using setInterval(sendPlayerPositions, 16);

`setInterval()` is not a good idea for FPS networking. On a slow internet connection or any tiny networking issue or lag, you might get into problems.

The most efficient approach is to send data only when objects change:

- Object Created - where and what.
- Object Removed - where (and how - if you need explosion for example).
- Object starts to move - send direction and speed.
- Object speed changes - send speed change.
- Object stops - where it stops.
- Object changes direction while moving - send a new direction
- Object turns in place - where it looks.

Sure, you need to mirror units behaviour on the client and the server.

This way when the unit is not moving - you basically not sending any information.
Of if many units on the screen moving simultaneously - you only send one message for it.

Also, as you expect the same behaviour on the client and on the server - you can start moving on the client instantly if the player moves or jump - and send a message at the same time w/o waiting for an update from the server. It will improve the user experience a lot.

Bulk messages also a good optimization - especially for RTS-like control. When you can select multiple units and make them move simultaneously - combining multiple messages into one will increase networking performance a lot for WS.

> process.nextTick and setImmediate

It will confuse your backend login a lot.

`setInterval` is still can be used as the main game loop, as you still might need NPC to walk w/o player interactions, or so some other updates. As long as it's not polluting networking.